# Android ProgressBar looks different in different fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-progressbar

I have used the same ProgressBar in both my fragments and they look different. I would like to have ProgressBar in the following style which I am getting in one of my activities

[image]

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_prog"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     />
```

but I am getting the ProgressBar as like this in another activity

[image]

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_line"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:progress="0"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

How can i make the second one look like the first?

The second type is actually displayed in listView as progress for each element

Comment: Is the same theme applied?

Comment: Yes, just that I have included the progressbar as part of listview item layout but outside the listview it works as the first.

Comment: One sets `paddingBottom`, other does not. If that is the issue its best to just delete your question (basically a typo)